# BIM-IOT integration through Autodesk platform services

Tags: javascript, visualization, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, forge

I want to do BIM IOT integration of Construction assets and I have data like available in pic, can I show this type of data on Autodesk platform services along with Revit model.
[Batching plant dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV09a.jpg)

Clarification regarding it and how can I do it through Autodesk platform services.

Answer (score 0):

The platform is quite diverse when it comes to the use of it. The answer is yes you can, but it will be based on your development skills. Here is a sample that represents data being passed on as extensions when using the viewer. This should be a good starting point for your development - https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo

You can start with this tutorial and continue building with the dashboard section and then start looking into the Data Viz extension. https://tutorials.autodesk.io/

Comment: How should I start like first I should make simple viewer like AutoDesk platform services tutorial or for IoT data visualisation thing some other way

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: Company is not giving me direct access to IOT data , they are giving me excel so can I put excel data as a IoT data or can I use excel data into data visualisation extension.